# Simple TextWrangler Grep Replace

Tags: regex, search, grep, aptana, textwrangler

I am trying to replace all h2 tags containing the class "title" with h1:

```
<h2 class="title">Things</h2>
```

I'm using the Multi-File search in TextWranger with this:

```
<h2 class="title">[^>]*</h2>
```

I'm able to find everything, but when I hit replace, it replaces my titles with the grep crap.

```
BEFORE: <h2 class="title">Things</h2>
AFTER:    <h1 class="title">[^>]*</h1>
```

My problem is that the search not only replaces my tags but also replaces my content with [^>]*. I also tried this in Aptana and the same thing happened. I would appreciate some insight.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It looks like you're converting `<h2 class="title">` to h1? You have to use a backreference in your "replace":

Search: `<h2 class="title">([^>]*)</h2>`

Replace: `<h1 class="title">\1</h1>`   (aside- if it's a h1 do you still want to preserve the 'class="title"'?)

Note the brackets in the search regex, which save what's inside them.

Then you use `\1` to pull them back out in the replace text (\1 for the first set of brackets, \2 for the second, ... )

Comment: Thank you, the backreference was precisely my problem.

Comment: Depending on your regex engine you may need to use `$1` to backreference the matching group